# How to restructure Qualtrics data via R using array or loop function

Tags: arrays, r, loops, sas, qualtrics

I have uploaded Qualtrics data that utilized a loop and merge function.

Currently, my variables in my data are as outline:
`Student1` `Student2` `Student3` `Q1_Student1` `Q1_Student2` `Q1_Student3`

What can I do to re-structure this so that it is long vertically rater than wide. That is, I would only have these two variables (with each student and respective responses in cells:
Student Q1

I would it to look like this: 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCM7t.jpg)

Any ideas? Does anyone have a script for this in either R or SAS? Thank you for your time, everyone!

Comment: The function that you are looking for is `melt` from the `reshape2` package, but without more information about what your data looks like, or how you want it to be, I don't think anyone will be able to help further.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for responding. See the edits I made in my post above. I added a picture of an example.

Comment: Are you certain that qualtrics doesn't have a different option for exporting data? I'd be surprised if they didn't, that's an incredibly useless form.

Comment: Yes, there is no other way to export data from Qualtrics :(

Comment: Please explain why in your restructured data you want cell B2 to contain 1 and cell B3 to contain 2. Do you neglect all `*.*.Chouce2`? Probably you should show us more data.

Comment: I've used qualtrics and my data didn't come out like that...anyways, post some more detail data and preferably not in a picture. It makes it easier than having to type out sample data...

Comment: Hello Dirk, 

Thank you for your response. I am not neglecting choice 2. I'll try to illustrate in an example. The first question is "Was (student) placed in an internship site?" and the responses are "yes (1)" or "no (2)"

Instead of giving me results that show 1 or 2, Qualtrics dummy coded the results and broke it down into these two variables. "Question1_Choice1" which represents yes and "Question1_Choice2" which is no. If the user selected no, they would get a 1 in the choice2 column and a 0 in the choice1 column.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your survey, not the data.  Based on the data you've shown, you are looping over Student1 and Student2 and within the loop you are asking a multi-select multiple choice question with two choices. This results in four columns in your data file: Loop1/Choice1, Loop1/Choice2, Loop2/Choice1, Loop2/Choice2.  You've essentially asked four questions, so there is no way to "convert" it to one answer.

Based on on what you say you want the data to look like, you don't need a loop and you should have a single response multiple choice question.

Each row in the data is a response (you have two responses).  Based on your question, it seems you are confusing Students (loops) with Respondents.

**Edit Based on Comment:**

A few things:

1. Name your questions Q1, Q2, etc. (instead of all Q1)
2. The # of students question should be outside the loop.  Then you need to add a MC question with Student 1, Student 2, etc. (up to max number of students) with display logic on each option based on the # of students question.  You need to add javascript to hide it.  Then loop based off the displayed options in your hidden question.
3. The Yes/No question in the loop should be a single response multiple choice.  You'll have as many columns for the question as you have options (Student 1, Student 2, etc.) in your hidden question.

Comment: There was no other around the survey. Here is an example of the survey loop:

Q1: How many students did you have this semester? 
  # User provides numerical value 
Q1: Was student 1 placed in an internship? 
Q1: Was student 2 placed in an internship?

Comment: I edited the answer based on your comment.  I hope it helps.